# Amazon S3 storage options -- Which is best/cheapest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When uploading a file to Amazon S3, there are three options:

1. Standard storage
2. Standard-IA (Infrequent Access)
3. Reduced Redundancy

Which one is the cheapest? Is it common to lose data by choosing Reduced Redundancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several [Amazon S3 storage classes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html), each with their own mix of cost/benefit.

**Standard** and **Standard-Infrequent Access** both store copies of the data in **3 different data centers** (Availability Zones).

The difference between them is purely pricing. Taking [current (July 2017) prices](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) in US regions:

- Standard: $0.023 per GB
- Standard-IA: $0.0125 per GB

However, Standard-IA has a **data retrieval price of $0.01 per GB**. This means that it is only worthwhile if you access the data, on average, less than once per month.

There are also higher charges for Get/Put on Standard-IA and a minimum charge of 30 days storage. Full details are on the [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

So, a general rule of thumb is: **Use *Standard-Infrequent Access* if you access the data infrequently (duh!), such as less than once per month**. This makes it ideal for backups, with the benefit of being highly durable and instantly available.

[**Reduced Redundancy**](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/reduced-redundancy/) was a way of obtaining lower-cost storage by only storing one redundant copy of data instead of two. That is, being stored in a total of two AZs instead of three AZs. However, in pricing reductions in late 2016, the cost of Standard storage was reduced but **Reduced Redundancy pricing was not lowered**. As a result, **Reduced Redundancy is now more expensive than standard storage**, at $0.0240 per GB.

Therefore, **there is no longer any reason to use Reduced Redundancy**. Why is this? Probably to encourage customers to use Standard-IA instead, which is more durable.

Then, of course, there is **Amazon Glacier** storage, which is even lower priced at $0.004 per GB but requires some retrieval time. This is ideal for **long-term archival storage** where data does not need to be immediately retrieved. (There is, however, the ability to retrieve the data within a few minutes for a higher cost.)

Comment: Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) is still lower than Standard in some regions where overall costs are higher. In São Paulo, Standard is $0.0405 and RRS is $0.0326.  In Singapore, Standard $0.0250 vs. RRS $0.0240.